# Waiting for DONE Job state - Dart Client for BigQuery

Tags: dart, google-bigquery, dart-async

The Dart Client for Bigquery is async, one needs to poll for job state as per the **Java code below**. 
How can I achieve same in Dart?

```java
//Java Equivalent
Job job = bigquery.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, runJob).execute();
String status = job.getStatus().getState();
while(!status.equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")) {
status = bigquery.jobs().get(PROJECT_ID,  job.getId()).execute().getStatus().getState();       
System.out.println("Status: " + status);
Thread.wait(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```dart
Future poll() {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1), () => job.getStatus().getState()).then((e) {
    if(e.done) {
      somethingToDoAfterGotState());
    } else {
      return poll();
    }
  });
}
```

(not tested)